# Opening filetype using java and a specific .jar

Tags: java, jar

I work in computational chemistry, so I need to view a lot of files (.cell, .geom, .castep, etc.) using JMol, a .jar molecular viewer. Is there any way I can set these filetypes to open in JMol by default in Windows 10, so that I can simply double click them like I can with other molecule viewers? Obviously setting them to open with Java or the .jar file individually doesn't work, and I can't figure out how to open the files with both.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Ah sorry I meant to put it in the main post - Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You can set-up new filetype handlers within Windows Explorer for each filetype you specified, BUT only if you can work out the command that launches JMol to example file of each type as:

```
C:\absolutepathto\jmol.bat file
```

You will need to fix your PATH to reference javahome\bin directory and set JMOL_HOME. Alternatively you can edit your version of jmol.bat or make your own a copy of jmol.bat which calls the original with the settings of JMOL_HOME / PATH, or add:

```
set JMOL_HOME=\pathto\jmol
set JAVA_HOME=\pathto\javahome
rem Replace java ... with:
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java ...
```

Then to register these scripts, right mouse on example of each file type and choose -> Properties to see the dialog, click Open with... "Change" and browse to pick your own version `C:\absolutepathto\jmol.bat`.

Hopefully then at next double-click from Explorer your script is launched. If it doesn't run add this as last line of the jmol.bat:

```
pause
```